# Postfix a comma if angularJS expression is not null

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to display an address on the View. Something like 
123 Street, 12 Apartment, 1 Floor, Richardson, Texas, 75081

User may skip entering the value of Floor for instance, and in that case I'll have to remove the comma visible after floor. Need something like -

```
{{streetAddress + ", "}}{{apartment + ", "}}{{floor + ", "}}{{city + ","}}{{state + ","}}{{zipCode}}
```

As in `comma` should be displayed only that expression has some value and is not null.

In the above statement if Floor is empty, it would display  - Street, null, Apartment...
I am trying to avoid tedious writing like

```
<span ng-show="streetAddress">{{streetAddress}},&nbsp;</span>
<span ng-show="floor">{{floor}},&nbsp;</span>
```

and so on..

Answer (score 1):

If the case of needing the comma is just isolated to this address the controller you should be enough. However, if you could think of a case where you would want to share this functionality throughout your app I would suggest a filter to handle adding the comma.

```
angular.module('yourModule', []).filter('commaFilter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input ? input + 'j' : '';
  };
});
```

used like

```
{{ streetAddress | commaFilter }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the controller:

```
var fullAddress = [],
components = [fullAddress,apartment,floor,city,state,zipCode];
// ES5
components.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item) {
    fullAddress.push(item);
  }
});
// pre-ES5
for (i=0;i<components.length;i++) {
  if (components[i]) {
    fullAddress.push(components[i]);
  }
}
$scope.fullAddress = fullAddress.join(",");
```

And then your template is easily:

```
<span>{{fullAddress}}</span>
```